# How to reduce spring-shell startup time?

Tags: performance, startup, jython-2.7, spring-shell

I'm using spring-shell and I want to reduce startup time of the shell.
Now it's taking 8-10 seconds and I want it to take less.
Do you have any suggestions?

By profiling I can see:

- org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.exec(String) takes **~2 sec**:

  - org.python.core.imp.importOne(String, PyFrame, int) - import jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar\Lib_jyio.py takes **~1 sec**.
- org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.(ScriptEngineFactory) takes **~0.5** sec

Thanks.